# "Any question is a good one for 48 hours."

Tags: discussion

Could we make it a rule that any question asked **in good faith** will be allowed to stay open for **at least 48 hours**? This would give honest retrocomputing-related questions that don't adhere to Stack Exchange's strict rules enough time to (1) provide something useful to the person who submitted the question, (2) without littering the site long-term. I believe goal (2) should not be allowed to override (1) and I think this would be a good compromise.

Comment: I share your wish to see more questions answered than closed (I'm typically reluctant to vote to close a question, and will usually edit it or skip), but I don't feel this is a good mechanism to do it.

Comment: If it's an RC.SE related question, why do you assume it gets closed? And what does 'good faith' has to do with that - beside, I think, that it's safe to assume every question is asked in good faith. So basically you're saying on topic questions should not be closed - which AFAIK is the very basic rule for RC.SE, isn't it? So what's the logic of this request?

Comment: @Raffzahn Are you saying that retrocomputing questions never get closed here?

Comment: @snips-n-snails There are many reasons to close a question, being about retro computing isn't one of them. But instead of asking what seams a rhetoric question, wouldn't you mind to add some content to your original question, especially what it's about and what the logic is you (want to) apply?

Answer (score 1):

### No.

There are many, many issues with this, including:

- What's good faith?
- If a question is answerable, why should we be trying to close it?
- If a question isn't (easily) answerable, we have to be able to put it on-hold before answers come in so it can be fixed.

It also doesn't provide clear benefits:

- If people still want to help the asker of an off-topic / shopping recommendation question, comments are still available.

It'd also provide a bad example:

- If all questions are allowed, then all questions are allowed.
- If not all questions are allowed, then which close-worthy questions are temporary-exemption-worthy?

I'm struggling to articulate why this is a bad idea, but… just no. Really, no.

Comment: "If a question isn't (easily) answerable, we have to be able to put it on-hold before answers come in" appears to contradict itself.

Comment: @snips-n-snails It's badly worded; I've never had to put this into words before. (I feel like this is an exam, and I'm not passing. ☺) If it's too broad, we need to put it on-hold in order to narrow it down before answers come in, or else we'll have answers that don't answer the question.

Comment: I think even those answers have value.

Comment: @snips-n-snails They do have value – but to different questions. If a question is narrowed so the answers no longer answer it, the answers shouldn't be there; they should be on different questions instead. Asking multiple, specific question is better than asking one broad one.

Comment: Even today, if an answer doesn't answer a question, we write a comment and/or downvote it, and the person who submitted the answer can modify or delete it. Anyway, earlier you asked, "If a question is answerable, why should we be trying to close it?" Here's a question that could easily be answered by a person with the necessary inside information, and yet there are 4 votes to close it: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11838/why-is-the-original-altair-basic-for-the-8080-cpu-source-code-not-available-on

Comment: @snips-n-snails [And three review votes to keep it open](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/close/7958) – the maximum the system permits. You haven't picked an uncontroversial example there.